# How to check if a variable of type Func<...> is a specific class method

Tags: c#, casting, func

I would like to check in runtime that a variable of type Func<...> is a specific class method.
E.g.

```
class Foo
{
    public static int MyMethod(int a, int b)
    {
        //...
    }
}

Func<int, int, int> myFunc;
myFunc = Foo.MyMethod;

if(myFunc is Foo.MyMethod)
{
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to compare the two directly using `==`:

```
if (myFunc == Foo.MyMethod) { ... }
```

Comment: Nice... I hadn't spotted that `Delegate` overloads `==`, and I'm somewhat surprised that the method group conversion works. But it does...

Comment: Careful though. It works fine here, but a `Delegate` instance may have more than one invocation, and even if the method you want is one of the ones in the invocation list, the equality comparison will return `false` in that case. Also, it seems to me that if you have code where you need to check which single method is invoked by the delegate, there's probably something bigger going wrong with the design there.

Comment: @PeterDuniho You are right about the code smell, but I need a quick workaround till I will come up with the proper solution